# $fopen returns the MCD, but the MCD does not work

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fopen, modelsim

I'm trying to open a file and write stuff, simple. My implementation is not so simple.
I'm using Verilog/SystemVerilog and Modelsim on the Windows OS. My command line in Modelsim is:

```
set generics "-gLOG_FILENAME=log_file?.txt"
vsim -onfinish stop -noglitch -voptargs=+acc -t ns filetest {*}$generics
```

The question mark is to try and create a file open error.

My Verilog module is

```
`include        "./simulationDefs.v"

module filetest
#( // Parameter passed in via the vsim command line
parameter LOG_FILENAME
)();

integer log_handle;

initial
    begin
        $display("log_handle=%h", log_handle); // Print MCD
        `log_file_open(LOG_FILENAME, log_handle); // Open File
        $display("log_handle=%h", log_handle); // Print MCD again
        $fdisplay(log_handle, "Test"); // Try to write to file
    end
endmodule
```

And my file open macro is:

```
`define log_file_open(log_filename, log_handle) \
        $display("Attempting to open log file - filename=%s", log_filename); \
        log_handle = $fopen(log_filename, "a"); \
        if (log_handle) $display("Success, log file opened - log_handle=%h", log_handle); \
        else $display("****ERROR LOG FILE NOT OPENED**** filename=%s", log_filename);
```

And finally my sim output:

```
# Start time: 15:24:21 on Oct 10,2023
# Loading sv_std.std
# Loading work.filetest
# log_handle=xxxxxxxx
# Attempting to open log file - filename=log_file?.txt
# Success, log file opened - log_handle=80000003
# log_handle=80000003
# ** Warning: (vsim-3535) [FOFIA] - Failed to open file "log_file?.txt" for appending.
# 
# Invalid argument. (errno = EINVAL)    : ft.v(18)
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /filetest
# ** Error (suppressible): (vsim-PLI-3085) ft.v(18): $fdisplay : Argument 1 is an unknown file descriptor.
#    Time: 0 ns  Iteration: 0  Instance: /filetest
```

`$fopen` is getting a valid MCD (multichannel descriptor), but after the macro checks its validity, the simulator outputs a "Failed to open file" error, and the next attempt to write to that file fails due to unknown file descriptor. If I remove the ? so the filename is valid, it all works. What's going on here? Why do I get a valid MCD when in fact the file did not open?

Comment: So it works fine, i.e. detects an error if I don't provide the second parameter on the $fopen. So it does appear to be a vendor bug of some sort. Thanks for checking this out. I look into appending to a file without the "a".

Comment: For future readers using Modelsim Altera Starter Edition 10.4d Revision 2015.12 I did some further experiments with these results. If I try and open for appending a legal filename (existing or not) with $fopen with the "a" or "a+" I get a correct fd of 8000_0003. And if the file name is illegal and use the "a+" I get and fd of zero which is also correct. But if I use an "a" then an incorrect fd of 8000_0003 is returned even though the file was not opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open a file in "append" mode, and apparently it succeeds on your file system.  I can open a file with a question mark in its name on my linux OS.

When it can do so, `$fopen` returns a non-zero file descriptor.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.3.1 *Opening and closing files*:

> The function **$fopen** opens the file specified as the filename argument
> and returns either a 32-bit multichannel descriptor or a 32-bit file
> descriptor, determined by the absence or presence of the type
> argument.
>
> The file descriptor *fd* is a 32-bit packed array value. The MSB (bit
> 31) of a fd is reserved and shall always be set

Since you use the 2-argument form of `$fopen`, it returns a file descriptor, which is a number whose MSB is always set.  This is why your `if (log_handle)` check is true.

Note that the way you call `$fopen`, it does not return a multichannel descriptor (MCD).

I tried an experiment where I called `$fopen` with a "r" type (open for reading), and the file descriptor was 0.

I don't understand why Modelsim returns a non-zero file descriptor (80000003), but then shows you that warning message.  That could be a tool bug.  You should contact the vendor.

Comment: 80000003 hex is a negative number, probably has something to do with internal modelsim works. one should probably check `if (log_handle >= 0) success...`

Comment: I get the same file descriptor when I successfully open a file with a legal file name I get the same 0x8000_0003 which is the crux of the problem, no way to tell if the open succeeded.